# Converting NFA to DFA using TG and RE

Tags: computer-science, automata, regular-expressions

how can I convert this NFA to DFA [image: NFA]

In school we are told that, to do this conversion first we have to convert this NFA to TG (transition graph) and then find the RE (regular expression) of TG and then convert it into DFA.
The TG which I found is [image: TG]

The RE of this TG, which I found, is    $ r=(01)^*+1^*+(00(11+1))^*$

Now to find DFA I can use Kleene Theorem: $r_1=(01)^*,r_2=1^* , r_3=00(1+11)$ so $r$ becomes $r=r_1+r_2+r_3^*$

Is this solution correct?

Comment: I am quite surprised that you were told to first compute a regular expression and then to convert it to a DFA. Have you ever heard of the [Powerset construction](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Powerset_construction)?

Comment: No I haven't. And we are bounded to solve such problem using the method stated above.